# Visual Studio 2013 Publish issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, publish

I converted a VS2010 ASP.Net MVC3 project to VS2013 MVC4. Now when I publish, it is copying the contents of my project to the bin folder.

[image]

I can't understand what I did to make it do this..How do I fix it so it doesn't do it?

Comment: How did you make the conversion from MVC-3 to MVC-4?

Comment: Manually, created new project copied stuff over.

Comment: Is the stuff in these folders (in the project) marked with a Copy To Output value?  Normally, content files should all be set to Do Not Copy.

Comment: "Copy if newer" for items IN the folders.

Comment: After looking in the bin folder of the project, for some reason, it actually has those folders and files in it. I removed them and are now republishing. Is it possible to just copy the project's publish.xml file from the VS2010 project to use with the VS2013 project? If so, how? They look totally different.

Comment: But after removing and republishing, they got published back into the bin folder again.

Comment: "Normally, content files should all be set to Do Not Copy" I guess I was confused. I set them to Do Not Copy and it is correct now. Post that as answer and I'll accept. Do files in the App_Code folder need to also be set to Do Not Copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files are incorrectly set to copy to the output folder (`\bin`) during build.  Make sure that the `Copy To Output` setting on each file is set to `Do Not Copy`.

Normally, you don't need to copy much of anything to your bin folder.  When publishing, all of the content pages (*.aspx, *.html, *.css, etc) will get picked up by publish just by existing in the project.  This is determined by the `Build Action` being set to `Content`.  (Note: you can exclude files by setting the Build Action to `None`)

For code files, there's 2 ways it could go. in a Web Application project (which MVC is) most code files, such as controllers, models, or code behind files in WebForms, are compiled into your site's DLL already.  These have `Build Action = Compile`, meaning they get compiled up front and don't need to be included in the publish.  The exception to this is files in App_Code, which are deployed to your site (`Build Action = Content`) and compiled at runtime.  You can also choose to pre-compile your site in the publish settings (Settings -> File Publish Options -> Precompile during publishing), which will process the App_Code files automatically (i.e. you can leave them as `Build Action = Content` and VS will compile them and publish the output instead).

Comment: So when we publish mvc application , models and controllers will not be included in preview files?

Comment: @xrx215 Correct, they are all compiled into the binary output.  There's no reason to publish the source code, as MVC does not use a build-on-the-fly compilation.